# SASL (DIGEST-MD5) authentication error with SMACK

Tags: xmpp, smack, sasl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SASL Authentication failed while integrating facebook chat using Smack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498260/sasl-authentication-failed-while-integrating-facebook-chat-using-smack)

I tries to compile this code and always it raises this exception

> SASL authentication failed using mechanism DIGEST-MD5:
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:325)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:395)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:349)
>       at SimpleConnection.main(SimpleConnection.java:31)

Code :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

public class SimpleConnection {

    static String username = "";
    static String password = "";

    public SimpleConnection() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

           SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5", MySASLDigestMD5Mechanism.class);
            ConnectionConfiguration conf = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
            XMPPConnection con = new XMPPConnection(conf);
            con.connect();
            con.login(username, password);

            //Chat c = con.getChatManager().createChat("atopmax", new aa());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The exception is saying you've got an authentication error. Have you double checked your username and password?

Comment: ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com",5222,"chat.facebook.com");
connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
connection.connect();
connection.login(userName, password);